# Calling PHP function nl2br in html doc

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a site in which I have a user entry field that I would like to insert line breaks after every new line in the user input without making an entirely new php page. Here's my code (js):

```
var newstreamSummary = document.getElementById("addNewstreamSummaryBox").value;
        if(newstreamSummary !== ""){
            document.getElementById("previewNewstreamSummary").innerHTML = newstreamSummary;
            /* newstreamSummary = <?php echo nl2br(newstreamSummary);?> */
        }
```

That block lives in a js function called showPreview(), when running it says the showPreview() is not defined. It also does not work when I put the php call in a separate `<script>` tag. I would like to call this function without having a new page as this is the only time in the project where I'm using php currently. Or if there's a js function that does the same thing. Thanks all for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php is server side. The only way of using php in that case would be making an Ajax call
to a php script which processes your test and returns this text processed.

There is no need for that in your case. Just add this line after your if statement:

```
newStringSummay = newStringSummay.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

Comment: Thank you Hidran this is exactly what I was looking for! Would you mind explaining that code snippet if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: the first argument is a regular expression that says: find all new lines(globally) and replace them with the second paramater:<br>